# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator, deploying cluster with multiple machines

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm trying to understand clustering of WSO EI. We can deploy each instance of WSO2 to separate Virtual Machines and place load balancer to make them work as one.

However, there are several questions which documentation does not answer.

1. Where shared database should be located? Do I need to deploy separate Virtual Machine just for database?
2. Where loadbalancer should also be located?

I can understand how to create cluster when single Virtual Machine is being used, but when its about multiple Virtual Machines it is hard to understand.

When I want to launch multiple instances in one Virtual Machine, it has its own question:

- How to launch multiple instances of WSO2 EI in one machine? Do I need to have multiple copies of same WSO2 and launch them spearately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where shared database should be located? Do I need to deploy separate
>   Virtual Machine just for database?

It depends. As you understand all instancess shall share a single database, technically it is not important where the database is (separate VM, one of the wso2ei VMs, ..). However - most of the time you deploy multiple VM for reliability reasons and then the reliability should concern the database too. Then separate DB instances (or DB service) would be more appropriate.

> Where loadbalancer should also be located?

It is the same consideration as for the databases.

> How to launch multiple instances of WSO2 EI in one machine? Do I need
>   to have multiple copies of same WSO2 and launch them spearately?

Yes. Create copies, set their port offset and you're good to go.

Comment: For the last question. So I copy and paste multuiple times WSO EI directory and launch them separately?

Comment: do not forget about the port offsets (in the carbon.xml) I have to admin I've never used the newest wso2ie, but it works for all other products from WSO2